# NSDate : Add a day based on Time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

In my app, I am getting a Date and start time of the same date and end time. The end time could be the time of very next day.

```
example : Date : 11/01/2011
          start time : 5:30 PM
          end time :   4:30 AM (of next day morning)
```

I am not getting the End Date.

How can I add one day into the start date based on the end time. I've referred many answers at SO but could not find the solution.

Comment: your question is not clear. Can you please specify some of the points like where are you getting it and how do you want to change the date.

Comment: I am getting it from server using web service

Comment: Hello, what is the final solution for this. When you don't have end date.

Comment: @MinuMaster : see my answer below... As I want to add one day only...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use this function

```
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:86400];
```

here 86400 is 60(seconds)*60(minutes)*24(hours).
If your startDate is not from current date then you can use this method

```
- (id)initWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)secsToBeAdded sinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

now you are getting like this

```
example : Date : 11/01/2011
          start time : 5:30 PM
          end time :   4:30 AM (of next day morning)
```

so you can have two dates, represents start time and end time. Use below method to get time interval

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSince1970
```

now you have two time interval for two different dates, right? Now simply subtract it and you will get what you want.

Comment: how can I get NSTimeInterval of 5:30 PM to 4:40 AM ? as i don't have date of 4:30 AM ???

Comment: I dont have two dates.. only one date with start time and have end time. Now based on End time I have to calculate the date whether end time is for the same date or next date.

Comment: It was so simple n straight forward but at first I could not understand what you were saying...

Comment: still one thing ending time get changed..It should be 4:30 AM but it gives 5 PM !!!

Comment: can you please post the code of getting start date and end date?

Comment: NO NO NO NO NO!!! This method is only useful if you're looking to add *exactly* 86,400 seconds to the point in time. It is INSUFFICIENT to use this method to add 1 day, because not every day has 86,400 seconds in it. You should be using `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar` instead.

Comment: actually in my case, I just wanted to check that given time is of next day or not means endTime < startTime, if so then just add one day in end date

Answer (score 2):

Solved : according to Akkis's answer...

```
    NSDate *startDate = [df dateFromString:startingDateTime];   
    NSDate *endDate = [df dateFromString:endingDateTime];

    NSComparisonResult result;
    result = [startDate compare:endDate];

    if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
    {
        NSLog(@"newDate is greater");

        endDate = [endDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dirty (NO DST check) method:  It's easier if you convert everything to common units (i.e. NSTimeInterval / double seconds). Check if end time is less than start time (converted to seconds from midnight).  Subtract startSeconds from endSeconds, if result is negative add 24 hours worth of seconds (24*60*60 = 86400).  Add result to start date/time.